# "Error invoking Lambda: Unable to execute HTTP request: Read timed out"... for a simple POST request?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, https, aws-lambda, axios

I'm struggling to do a simple POST request without it failing with this message :

`Error invoking Lambda: Unable to execute HTTP request: Read timed out`

My Lambda code consists of this :

```
const axios = require("axios");
const api = require('lambda-api')();
let PROJECT_ID = process.env.PROJECT_ID_CREATE
let TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN

api.post("/api-gitlab-launcher/create", async (lambdaRequest, res) => {
            return {
                "ami_id": lambdaRequest.body["ami_id"],
                "ip_address":lambdaRequest.ip
            }
    }
)

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    let config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/trigger/pipeline?token=${TOKEN}&ref=terraform-v1-mirror`,
        headers: {}
    };

   await axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    return await api.run(event, context);
}
```

This problem has been driving me mad for days... And I can't pinpoint where the bug is! If someone has an idea where it could from, I'd be glad.

**UPDATE**

It does work locally. Just tested it and the POST request is sent when run locally. I checked with the VPCs and it's allowing all outbound traffic.

**UPDATE 2**
[image]

Comment: So your Lambda is running inside the VPC?

Comment: In your case, lambda has to do nothing with VPC so forget about that VPC and Lambda are independent services. How are you hitting this API locally, from any rest client or using node js code?

Comment: @ChandanKumar I am hitting this API via the node.js code. I tried hitting it with Postman and it worked. I tried hitting it locally using the AWS Lambda code and it worked. When deploying it at AWS it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Can you share us your request and response of Postman. You can update your question with these details.

Comment: Where is your gitlab? Have you hosted it on EC2?

Comment: No, gitlab is just an online repository, where another project is stored. I'm seeking to trigger a pipeline there via the API.
I didn't host it either way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220149/discussion-between-chandan-kumar-and-fares).

Comment: @Fares can you come on chat?